# mongo db conditional update, push data

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a MongoDB database structured as follows:

```
{
    accountName: "pippo",
    whishList: {
        element1: [
            { price: 25, time: '2024-02-20T20:00:00.000+00:00' },
            { price: 30, time: '2024-02-21T20:00:00.000+00:00' },
        ]
    }
}
```

I need to update this database with a function that receives a price as a parameter and pushes an object into the element1 list with this price and the current time (new Date()) only if the last price (the price of the last element of the list called element 1) is different from this price. If the document is not found in the collection, it should be created (with upsert true).

I tried this code but it doesn't work:

```
async function updatePrice(id, element, price) {
    const filter = { 
        accountName: id,
        $expr: { $ne: [ {$last : `whishList.${element}`}.price , price ] }
    }
    const update = {     
        $push: {
            `whishList.${element}`: {
                value: valore,
                time: new Date()
            }
        }
    };

    await prova.updateOne(filter, update, { upsert: true });
}
```

Comment: What do you post a [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78036602/mongo-db-conditional-push-data)? Have you checked out the duplicate link I posted in the previous question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `filter` criteria were incorrect:

1. You are not referring to the document field (missing `$`).
2. You do not correctly get the `price` last element from the `whishList.${element}` array.

Either you can do with `$getField`:

```js
const filter = {
  accountName: id,
  $expr: {
    $ne: [
      {
        $getField: {
          field: "price",
          input: {
            $last: `$whishList.${element}`
          }
        }
      },
      price 
    ]
  }
};
```

[Demo Approach 1 @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/GVFWteslF_O)

Or with dot notation:

```js
const filter = {
  accountName: id,
  $expr: {
    $ne: [
      {
        $last: `$whishList.${element}.price`
      },
      price 
    ]
  }
};
```

[Demo Approach 2 @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/YfAD5nwbbm7)